# Which bidding system is assumed by default at BBO?

Tags: bridge, duplicate-bridge

Which bidding system is assumed by default at [Bridge Base Online](http://www.bridgebase.com/) (for humans)?

I asked in chat several times in different games (ten times I think) and nobody answered.

Is it [Bridge base basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_Base_Basic)? Or maybe [YACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_American_Yellow_Card)?

Comment: Gittelman was keen to propagate his bidding theories, so I would assume Bridge Base Basic.

Comment: **Gittelman** is the founder of Bridge Base Online.

Comment: That you need to ask this question simply cements my resolve that bidding systems are table talk.

Answer (score 4):

Playing with random partners on BBO is pretty frustrating. You will find a lot of "advanced" players playing "SAYC" who:

1. make minimal offshape takeout doubles
2. make minimal (off or on)-shape takeout doubles, then freebid
3. interpret your jumps in competitive auctions as strong
4. "weak 2 bid" = "I have a six card suit and a bad hand"
5. "penalty double" = "I am sad that the other side won the auction"
6. "five hearts" = "I am in denial that the other side won the auction"
7. 2C = "I have 17 high card points and a singleton"
8. 4NT = universal language of love.

These bad habits aside, there's still the problem of unfamiliarity with each other's conventions, etc. My advice is: use minimal gadgetry, pass a lot, when you know that someone at the table is lying, don't automatically assume it isn't your partner, and, eventually, when you find a partner who, if not necessarily good, doesn't violate (1)-(8) above, add them as "friend" and then you can play with them the next time you are both on BBO instead of going fishing in the void.

Comment: How true. Sounds like bad players abound on the internet as well as in physical clubs everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer- No system- its an open community. If high level players like JEC don't need to specify a system why would anyone else. 
Partial answer- Most English speaking bridge players are American so can assume they play some sort of Standard American- they assume you are psychic so you know what they play.